# Rails - is it possible to redirect to a custom path with params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, authorization

So I am making an authorisation system. A new registration page is set to be '/signup'. If registration is invalid (username has already been taken, password too short), I want to show the errors. When I do it like this:

```
@user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to stories_path, notice: "Thanks for registration!"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
```

it works, but it renders in '/users' instead of '/signup'. And when instead of

render 'new'

I write

redirect_to '/signup'

it redirects, but errors are not shown. Is it possible to redirect to '/signup' and keep the errors?

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    validates :username, presence: true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
    validates :password, presence: true, :length => {minimum: 6}
end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.create(user_params)
        if @user.save
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            redirect_to stories_path, notice: "Thanks for registration!"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
    end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<h3>New registration</h3>

<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
   <div> <%= f.input :username %>
    <%= f.error :username %></div>
    <div><%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.error :password %></div>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

and routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'stories#index'
  resources :stories
  resources :users
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it works, but it renders in '/users' instead of '/signup'

It's normal behavior. The `/signup` page is the result of `new` action from `UsersController`. This page contains form. After submitting this form, data goes to `create` action from the same controller, but via `POST` method.

If validation will be failed controller will render `:new` template, as you remember `create` action has `/users` link. So you will see `:new` template in `/users` link.

Here is route map for `UsersController`:

```
          GET    /users(.:format)                users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)                users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)            users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            users#destroy
```

To achieve your requirements you can add route to `routes.rb`. And change the url in form.

Something like this:

```
post 'signup` => 'users#create`
```

And in form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, url: HERE_IS_SIGNUP_PATH) do |f| %>
```